# Design pattern for checking multiple conditions

Tags: design-patterns, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to figure out if there is a design pattern for the below scenario.

I have two types of objects say `List<JobApplicant>` jobApplicants and `List<Job>` jobs, I wanted to select all jobs for which a `JobApplicant` is eligible, eligibility criteria can be multiple like `JobApplicant` and job skills are matching, experience, location, etc. it can be multiple.

After running all kinds of eligibility criteria I can get all job lists for which a `JobApplicant` is eligible. I tried implementing this with the simple eligibility condition, but the condition will keep increasing when there is new eligibility comes.

Are there any design patterns that can describe such a system and/or help on this to make it generic so that we can keep adding more eligibility criteria to filter desired jobs for an applicant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather broad question, but let's see if I understood correctly. So you want to apply a set of criteria to two Lists right?

You can achieve this with a filter chain. Imagine that you have the following interface:

```kotlin
interface EligibilityCriterion {
    fun apply(jobs: List<Job>, applicant: JobApplicant): List<Job>
}
```

Now you would need to implement whatever eligibility criteria you have, being each one implementation of the `EligibilityCriterion` interface. The single method should return the `Job`s to which the applicant is still eligible.

In another class, you would get all your implementations of `EligibilityCriterion` as follows (I am assuming Spring for simplicity but you can get them any other way that applies to your case):

```kotlin
@Service
class JobsService(private val eligibilityCriteria: List<EligibilityCriterion>) {

   fun findJobsForApplicant(jobs: List<Job>, applicant: JobApplicant): List<Job>{
        eligibilityCriteria.fold(jobs) { jobsFold, eligibilityCriterion -> 
             eligibilityCriterion.apply(jobsFold, applicant) 
        }
   }

}
```

The idea here is that you apply one `EligibilityCriterion` at a time and the filtered `List<Job>` is then passed to the following `EligibilityCriterion` until all have been applied. In the end, you have all the `Job`s to which the `applicant` is eligible.

Given that you have a list of `JobApplicant`s you would need to iterate over them and apply the criteria to each and every one of them.

You can read more about this in the following online resources:

- https://www.baeldung.com/intercepting-filter-pattern-in-java
- https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility

P.S.: sorry for the Kotlin + Spring code, but I feel it is easier to explain and understand these things with code and not only words.